# Microsoft Team showing blank page for all SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint, office365, microsoft-teams

Teams suddenly stopped showing SharePoint list inside Teams's channel.
[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify your issue with error screenshots? or please check your app manifest contains [webApplicationinfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/creating-team-manifest-manually-for-webpart#create-a-microsoft-teams-app-manifest) property

Comment: Thanks Trinetra, just added screenshot

Comment: Does your app manifest have webApplicationInfo listed?

Comment: How do I find it? I am not running any custom code in O365.

Comment: It will be in your app manifest which is uploaded in Teams app store

Comment: Ok- but we have not done any changes and it was working fine last week and now every lists that we have added as a tab in our teams now started showing blank page nothing else.

BTW thanks for your continued response.

Comment: Could it be the reason that Microsoft has released some major updates in last week?

Comment: Are you still facing this issue?

Comment: Yes, I am stuck in it, I have cleared cache.

Comment: it would be good if you can provide us your manifest so we can test it at our end

Comment: You can use the website app as a fallback tab, until Microsoft corrects the issue.

Answer (score 2):

We've had the same issue and could resolve it just now. The Lists would only show up for certain users but, for most users, the page in Teams remained blank like yours.

The problem was that the lists were created in the team site of Team A and was then shared with users of Team B. Users of Team B would, however, only be able to view the list directly in a browser but not in Teams.

The issue was resolved by sharing Team A's team site with the users of Team B. This can be done like this (texts may vary):

- Enter the home page of the team site
- Click the gear icon in the top right
- Site permissions
- Invite user
- Only share site
- Members of the team that should have access

Comment: Good insight, but IMHO Microsoft still needs an official fix to this problem.  You may not want all of Team B to be visitors on Team A's libraries, lists and folders.  You may want to only instead share out specific libraries, but not others.